# Как сделать выпадающий элемент в Tabs?

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся с проблемой, использую **TabActivity**, и  нужно каким то образом сделать крайний правый **tab** чем-то вроде выпадающего списка "еще..." в котором будет еще пара кнопок, не знаю даже как и описать, лучше покажу:

[image]

Comment: А почему табы внизу? это не совсем хороший дизайн.
выберет пользователь "вкладку с выпадающего списка" и как это все потом отображать?

Может для начала взять классическое решение, а потом придумывать горе-дизайн?

И вообще, этот клас deprecated.

Comment: > Цитата выберет пользователь "вкладку с выпадающего списка"

а можно пример? я с вкладками еще не работал

Comment: >>дизайн не я разрабатываю
отберите у дизайнера айфон, дайте ему андроид. Потом пусть разрабатывает дизайн. А то делают бяку, а потом говорят - нет на андроиде нормальных программ.

>>а можно пример? я с вкладками еще не работал
Я и сам хотел бы пример, как это убожество будет в теории работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ох, это дурацкая особенность всех при всех дизайнеров, клиентов - смотреть на iPhone!!!!! Убейте их!

Так ведут себя нативно табы в ios, насколько я знаю.

У меня такая же задача стоит, точнее будет чуть позже. Я думаю, в Android-е - это(*БОЛЬШОЕ КОЛИЧЕСТВО ВКЛАДОК*) делается как в приложение Google Play Store - ViewPager(который есть в compability library) + компонент, аля вкладки, выпадалки.

**UPD**

Собственно вот: [пост](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) и  [viewpagerindicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)

Comment: > + компонент, аля вкладки, выпадалки. 
  
я так понимаю вы имели ввиду viewpagerindicator

с viewpager я работал.

Comment: да, но не только

Comment: если не только, то подскажите пожалуйста, как мне выкрутиться, а то поиски не дали результатов

Comment: что значит выкрутиться? тут дизайнер загнал, а вы будете себе мозг парить? объясните, что это айфоноваская шняга..а если нужно много вкладок пробуйте viewpagerindicator. Хм.

Comment: и вообще! за табы внизу - убил бы сразу!

Comment: хорошо, спасибо большое :)

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно по той кнопке открывать полноэкранный `Dialog` с прозрачным фоном.

В диалог передавай координату верхнего края кнопки и выравнивай кнопки диалога выше кнопки-табы.

Клик по любому месту диалога кроме меню айтемов закрывает диалог.